# JavaFx CSS style: Change left and right of selected

Tags: java, css, javafx

So in my Java Application I have a grid pane with a time table of various names. 
To change the color of the one my mouse is hovering over I do this:

```
.hours_grid_cell_pane:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #ffff00;
    -fx-border-color: #000000;
}
```

This is pretty simple. I want to know how I do the same thing to all the cells to the left, right, top, and bottom of the one I'm hovered over. Essentially forming big  where my mouse is. 
I've tried

```
.hours_grid_cell_pane:hover:left
```

and

```
.hours_grid_cell_pane:left
```

but that doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So you have the gridpane as a table? what kind of nodes are you using to represent the names?

Comment: You would have to write the code yourself to set the pseudoclass state for the custom pseudoclasses (`left`, `right`, etc), using handlers for mouse entered and mouse exited on each node in the grid pane. Without seeing how you are creating and managing those nodes, it's hard to give more help.